# Passing RUBY Array to C DLL using Fiddle

Tags: c, ruby, dll, fiddle

First I am aware that my question is similar to the one posted as the following.
[How to deal with array pointers in ruby Fiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19744000/how-to-deal-with-array-pointers-in-ruby-fiddle)

But that question is indeed not answered. My problem is to write a function in ruby, that will accept a ruby array of float as input and return a Fiddle::Pointer that can be processed in C DLL. Here is it

```
# transform an ruby array of double to Fiddle::Pointer and processed as double* in C DLL
# @param [Array] array the ruby array, e.g. [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
# @return [Fiddle::Pointer] fiddle pointer that could be processed as double * in C
def double_array_to_ptr(array)
  length = array.length
  ptr = Fiddle::Pointer.malloc(length * Fiddle::SIZEOF_DOUBLE)

  # initialize the ptr with numbers in array
  for i in 0..length-1
    # how to initialize the ptr
    # maybe ptr[start, length] would help, I have tried but no success

  end
  return ptr
end
```

And the C function may look like this

```
/**
 * \brief       H2OSetGlobalOffset set the global offset of data
 * \param[in]   H2OProjectH project project manager, this one has been initialized
 * \param[in]   double * offset offset data, the buffer is initilized in ruby 
*/
H2O_EXPORT void H2OSetGlobalOffset(H2OProjectH project, double* offset);
```

The function has been wrapped with Fiddle::Importer, which is the same as previous question. So the question is that how can I initialize the Fiddle::Pointer in the ruby code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
ptr = Fiddle::Pointer[arr.pack('E*')]
```

The `E*` is for little-endian byte order,

Got the above from this [Ruby forum link](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6878376)

For more on packing and unpacking of different data types [check this post](http://idiosyncratic-ruby.com/4-what-the-pack.html)

Comment: Can you please explain why is it been down voted? I recently moved one of my libraries from FFI to fiddle, and used the above code to create an array pointer and it works just fine.